# Angular 6: can't submit form in modal

Tags: angular, forms, post, popup, bootstrap-modal

I have an Angular 6 app of courses and I want to create a form inside modal that connected to forms keep and send the data there.
without the modal it's working and send the data to form keep, but when I'm working with modal it's not.

this is the html file and component file:

```html
<div class="row mt-3">
  <button class="upgrade" (click)="open(content)">Upgrade Academy</button>
</div>

<ng-template #content let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
    <span class="closes" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')">&times;</span>

    <div class="text-center jumbotron">
      <h1 class="display-4">Upgrade Academy!</h1>
      <p class="contact">Contact information</p>
      <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="https://formkeep.com/f/2f76e41ddc2a" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="first-name"></label>
          <input type="text" id="first-name" name="first-name" placeholder="First name*" class="field" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="last-name"></label>
          <input type="text" id="last-name" name="last-name" placeholder="Last name*" class="field" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email"></label>
          <input type="email" id="email-address" name="email" placeholder="Enter email*" class="field" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="organization"></label>
          <input type="text" id="organization" name="organization" placeholder="Organization*" class="field" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="message"></label>
          <textarea type="text" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Your message" rows="4" class="field" style="height:150px;"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <button class="submit btn btn-dark" type="submit">Get more information</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

```js
export class ComponentModal implements OnInit {

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private config: NgbModalConfig,
        private modalService: NgbModal,
        private activeModal: NgbActiveModal,
        private router: Router) {
          // customize default values of modals used by this component tree
          config.backdrop = 'static';
          config.keyboard = false;
        }

  open(content) {
    this.modalService.open(content, { size: 'lg' });
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

}
```

Comment: You should handle your forms the Angular way & use either [reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) or [template-driven forms](https://angular.io/guide/forms).

Comment: but I need to send the answer to formkeep. How can I combine them?

Comment: My recommendation - use your component to create the form (reactive or template-driven), create a HTTP service (to handle you FormKeep request) and send the data you get from your component to that service and have the service handle all the request related functionality.

Comment: and use POST request to the url of formkeep?

Comment: Indeed - [here is an example](https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request) of how you would make the HTTP post request from the official Angular documentation.

Comment: I have services for my backend so I know the basics. Is it really necessary to do a whole service just for one post function?

Comment: Ideally you would want to create a generic HTTP service that will handle all  HTTP requests (post, get, put, etc...) In this case you would want to utilize that generic HTTP service for FormKeep.